# Dart pub rename failed

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am using the Dart Editor and get the following error when I run pub get

> --- Dec 11, 2013 9:21:42 PM Running pub get ... --- Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies.......... Downloading json_object
>   1.0.18+2... Rename failed
>
> ** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **

What is going on here? I have downloaded many packages before.
How do I get a more meaningful error message?

Comment: Can you post your `pubspec` file?

Comment: I managed to get around this issue by running 'pub get' from the command line rather than via the Eclipse dart Editor. Oddly enough I can use Eclipse dart editor to download other packages

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with symlinks. 
You may try to empty your packages directory within your package and also try to empty your .pub-cache directory.

Comment: Where is the .pub-cache in windows?